# Using self created dll in Xamarin.Forms showing white screen on device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create and use a DLL in Xamarin.Forms Project. This is given in the Charles Petzold's book 'Creating Mobile Apps using Xamarin.Form'.
It gives the following method to access the library that I have created

**"From the PCL project of your application solution, add a reference to the library PCL assembly which is the dynamic-link library generated from the library project"**

My library project is this

FILE: HslColorExtension.cs

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit
{
    public static class Toolkit
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
        }
    }

    public class HslColorExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public HslColorExtension()
        {           
        }

        public double H { set; get; }
        public double S { set; get; }
        public double L { set; get; }
        public double A { set; get; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider servicePRovider)
        {
            return Color.FromHsla(H, S, L, A);
        }
    }          
}
```

THE actual project is CustomExtensionDemo
In that the MainPage.xaml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit;assemby=Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit"
             x:Class="CustomExtensionDemo.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="UTKARSH">
            <Label.BackgroundColor>
                <toolkit:HslColorExtension H="0" S="1" L="0.5"/>
            </Label.BackgroundColor>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

THE METHOD HOW I ADDED THE DLL TO THE APPLICATION
FROM THE LIBRARY IS TOOK THE PATH THAT GENERATED THE DLL
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit\Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit\obj\Debug
The name of the DLL is 
Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit.dll
[image]

I added the reference to the actual project. browsed the path to
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit\Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit\obj\Debug
and added the DLL : Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit.dll
[image]

Everything compiled correctly **But I am getting a complete white screen on the Android Phone I am having .**
POINTS:
 **1. I have set MainPage.xaml as the MainPage in the App.xaml.cs.**. I have tried to put Label without the property element syntax and that worked.

I have not checked on iOS I think that there it would have the same problem as the problem could be in method of using the DLL in the application.
IDE:VS 2017

THE ERROR THAT IS DISCUSSED IN THE BELOW DISCUSSION 
[image]

NOW I REQUIRE SOME WAY TO REMOVE THE "Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1" AND IT DOES NOT GIVE OPTION TO REMOVE THAT.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain your problem is incompatible targets of your PCL.

Instead of adding the reference by browsing for the DLL, add it by selecting the project.  This approach will check for compatibility of the DLL.  Most likely you will need to change targets, fool around with nuget, etc.

Secondly I would recommend that your first platform for testing be UWP.  There seems to be much better diagnostics on UWP.  When I tried your code, I got the white screen on Android, but when using UWP as a platform I got an exception that said the HslColorExtension could not be found in the DLL.

Comment: Yes, I tried to add that by adding the project. And it did not allow to add because of the target difference.It did show me the error. But then I tried to use the dll. But anyways the targets are differing.In my actual project the targets are everything that are present in the library project plus 'Windows phone silverlight 8'. And there is no method to remove it. What should be done. I am attaching the pic in above question

Comment: I have found some answers to this on this website. I is about playing around nugets. I will figure this out Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow these steps it should work for you:

1. You mis-spelled assembly as "assemby" in your XAML.

```
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit;assemby=Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit"
```

2. To make sure we're starting clean, let's just create a fresh Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit project and get rid of the one you've been using:

   a) Copy out the code that you've already written so you don't lose it.

   b) Create a new Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit project and only target those platforms that you would feasibly use this toolkit in.  For example you would never use this in Silverlight because you're going to be referencing IMarkupExtension which is specific to Xamarin Forms.

   c) Add a reference to your Toolkit project from your Xamarin Forms PCL project (looks like you're calling that "CustomExtensionDemo").  Don't reference the .dll but rather the project itself.  This will spare you other headaches down the road.

   d) Copy your HslColorExtension file (and any other classes you have) back in to the new project.

   e) Add the Xamarin.Forms Nuget package to your Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit PCL, and a "using Xamarin.Forms" line at the top of your HslColorExtension file so that it recognizes the IMarkupExtension interface.
3. Add an empty Init function (or call it whatever you want) to your HslColorExtension class and then call it from your App.xaml.cs.  This has the effect of "waking the compiler/linker up" to the fact that you have an assembly reference in XAML, since XAML is loaded at runtime.  It does seem a bit hokey to have to do this, but you can tuck away that ugliness in your App.xaml.cs and you never have to see it again.  If you're curious and want to see what's going on, try running it both with and without the call to Init, and take a look at your Android project's bin/Debug folder.  When you call Init you'll see your Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit.dll appear in that folder.  When you don't call Init it doesn't pull your assembly in.  That's the core issue here.

Your resulting markup extension code would look like this:

```
    public class HslColorExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public static void Init()
        {
        }

        public double H { set; get; }
        public double S { set; get; }
        public double L { set; get; }
        public double A { set; get; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Color.FromHsla(H, S, L, A);
        }
    }
```

And your App.xaml.cs like this:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            HslColorExtension.Init();

            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        ...
    }
```

If that doesn't solve it for you, let me know! :-)

Comment: Silverlight project is not getting created in the Xamarin.FormsBook.Toolkit  dll project but in the CustomExtensionDemo project. While creating the CustomExtensionDemo project never it asked whether Silverlight phone project is required or not. It just gave it in the project by default. That is to be changed from the UI. There are some ways to do this on this website

Comment: Did you get it working so that you can see your "UTKARSH" text?

Comment: I corrected the mistake of the 'assembly' word first. Also I think in your code above Initializecomponent() is not to be called in MainPage but in Application class. I changed the targets for both the projects (mine and DLL) I made both of them to reflect the same options.I was allowed to add the dll project as 'project' not as 'dll'  It compiled and everything went smooth. But this time I am getting an runtime exception but not in my code. The exception has no text associated with it. no breakpoints hitting. I think I will have to ask a new question on this website for this.

Comment: Also I am running windows on mac using bootcamp not an Windows independently. Just it case if that could be source of the problem..Don't know...

Comment: Correct, the Init() should be called from the Application class as I indicated above.  Since this helped you get past this first set of issues can you mark my response as the answer.  Also, good idea on creating another post for your other issue.  I'll keep an eye out for it.  Thanks!